# how to use svn while working on same file?

Tags: svn

How to use svn when two programmers are working on same file in same project?
do one programmer need to wait before other programmer commits his work on that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**do one programmer need to wait before other programmer commits his work on that file?**

To make sure two or more devs can work on same file at the same time is one of the purposes of any VCS. Most of the modern VCS, includes SVN, provide very advance conflict resolution mechanism.

If you happen to be working on the same file, changing the same line as your peer/s-- you can easily resolve it.

If you are working on difference places in the same file, SVN will merge the changes reliably and elegantly.

So, *do not worry; and do not stop working on code thinking someone else might be editing it.* :)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you have even tried to read the basic of SVN

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.copy-merge

This is what discussed in a very section of SVN official reference.